# Maximum profit by two parameters

Tags: algorithms

Suppose we have two markets. Each market has various **buy** & **sell** orders that we can **sell to** or **buy from** respectively. Each order represents a specific **number** of a particular **item type**  that someone is selling or buying for a specific **price per item** and we can buy/sell any amount of items from/to any order. Each item type has its own **volume per item** (m<sup>3</sup>).

We have transportion that can transport a specific amount of **volume** and some **budget amount**.

Our goal is to form such transport cargo load of items that would maximize our profit by going from station `A` to station `B` assuming our limited cargo capacity and budget.

The algorithm I'm using is the following:

1. Sort **sell** orders of the **source station** by `price_per_item` in ascending order and group them by `item_type`.
2. Sort **buy** orders of the **destination station** by `price_per_item` in descending order and group them by `item_type`.
3. For each item type, form pairs of sell-buy orders based on the `amount` available in both markets (e.g. `[Item, Quantity, Buy At, Sell At]: [Apple, 25, 50, 75], [Apple, 5, 50, 70], [Apple, 20, 60, 70]`)
4. Perform one of the following actions based on user input:

   - **(A)** Sort pairs by **profit per m<sup>3</sup>** (`sell_price - buy_price / volume_per_item`) in descending order.
   - **(B)** Sort pairs by **profit / buy price** ratio (`(sell_price - buy_price / volume_per_item) / buy_price` in descending order.
5. Take as many items as possible from each pair of the sorted list until either `budget = 0` or `cargo_capacity = 0` or there are no pairs left.

When using option **(A)**, the described algorithm doesn't take the budget into account while forming the list of most profitable pairs so it gives poor results with a limited budget. When the budget is high, due to the variety of the market the following algorithm uses a full budget amount while cargo space is usually almost empty (which I don't consider the acceptable result as I need to mitigate risks of losing cargo and having large losses due to low ROI).

When using option **(B)**, the gives good profit compared to the amount used to buy the items but it doesn't utilize available budget efficiently.

**So the task is to maximize `total_profit / total_buy_price` ratio while utilizing available `budget_amount` and `cargo_capacity` as much as possible.**

Does this fall under some type of mathematical problem that can be solved in a mathematical way, and if so, can you suggest some sources to read up on in detail? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are handling only one truck/cargo in your problem, then this is a typical  **Knapsack** problem. If you are handling the bigger problem of distributing all items on how many trucks, then it is a variant of **Bin Packing** problem. Both problems are **NP-Complete**, however **Knapsack** has approximate algorithms with guaranteed bounds from optimality.

I suggest you use a somehow mangling compromise between **A** and **B**:

1. Solve using **A**, then solve using **B** and take the best answer.
2. Do both sortings, keep 2 arrays, then at each step compare **A** choice to **B** choice and select the better choice (**greedy approach**)
3. Assign a weight to each factor then sort an array **C** according to your weight function. If you don't know the weights then make it equal (half for each factor). If you value price more make its weight above `0.5` if you value volume more then give it a higher weight. This is called **multiplicative weight**

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This particular problem turned out to be the **Bounded Knapsack Problem**. However, the mentioned problem doesn't include the budget limitations.

Answer (score -1):

this is an eve online question hahaha
just take the profit per item and divide it by it's size and sort descending
then fill in your cargo with as much as you can
this way you hit both in the same time

Comment: Welcome to [cs.se]! This question asks for a mathematical perspective on the problem. This means that beyond suggesting a method to solve the problem, we want to know how effective this method is in the general case, and find a mathematical proof of this fact. I think that your heuristic seems reasonable in the context where you apply it, but it may not be the most efficient method in general. Additionally, we prefer that answers are written carefully with full punctuation, and not how you would be sending chat messages.